# Service not working after CLI build, works fine with GUI build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nant

Recently one of the services that my group makes has stopped working when built via CLI.  It will build just fine, but upon installation it will give us an object reference error.  If I build the same service via GUI and install it, everything works just fine.  I currently build 25 different projects via script (NAnt) and all but the one in question work perfectly fine.

The file appears to be the same (size is identical), the output folder contains the exact same files (minus the vshost files from the GUI).  Both GUI and CLI are using the same build configuration.

I don't understand why this one project is requiring me to build it via the GUI to run correctly.  Can anyone give me any insight?

Comment: In the end I had to completely remake the solution for it to work.  The only thing I can guess at is that someone added a bad reference and I couldn't find it.  I know that the GUI will sometimes overlook a bad reference and fix it, while the CLI will not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the solution is in a comment: a bad reference the GUI passed over.